# How to parse multiple element attribute values in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have below xml;

```
<Main>
    <Item ItemID="123456">
        <Devtm PL="SP"></Devtm>
        <Devtm PL="RV"></Devtm>
    </Item>
</Main>
```

I am trying to get all values belonging Devtm element. This element can have multiple values with PL attribute.

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
        var lineItemDetails = xdoc.Descendants("Main");

        foreach (var lineItemDetail in lineItemDetails)
        {
            var Devtm = lineItemDetail.Element("Item")?.Element("Devtm")?.Attribute("PL")?.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(Devtm);
        }
    }
}
```

This is only giving me first element value which is "SP". How can i get the second value as well? I don't need to loop because i know that there are only 2 values there.

LINQ is also not an option for some reasons. How can i achieve it with XDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your code a little bit to get an expected result. Use [`Descendants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=netframework-4.8) method to access an `Item` element and then iterate through its nodes

```cs
var lineItemDetails = xdoc.Root?.Descendants("Item");

foreach (var lineItemDetail in lineItemDetails?.Nodes().OfType<XElement>())
{
    var Devtm = lineItemDetail?.Attribute("PL")?.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(Devtm);
}
```

It prints `SP` and `RV`.

If you want to use index-based access, without loop, this can help

```cs
var lineItemDetails = xdoc.Root?.DescendantsAndSelf("Item").FirstOrDefault();
var nodes = lineItemDetails?.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>().ToList();

Console.WriteLine(nodes?[0]?.Attribute("PL")?.Value);
Console.WriteLine(nodes?[1]?.Attribute("PL")?.Value);
```

Comment: is there a way to assign it to another variable like var Devtm[0] or var Devtm[1]?

Comment: @sensahin I've updated a code with index based access

Comment: is it possible to use access using index with foreach loop? the first solution that you provide?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand why/ It doesn't make sense, you access elements one by one in loop of use an index to access a specific one